# Get last inserted ID from mysql table

Tags: php, mysql

How to get the last inserted ID of a table, even if the last x record(s) have been deleted?

x can be 1 and can be like 200

Comment: You provided insufficient information, therefore the only logical conclusion is that you need the [last_insert_id()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id) function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're talking about auto incremented IDs:

```
SELECT AUTO_INCREMENT FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE table_name = 'Table'
```

This will give you the next increment id. To get the last inserted id just minus 1.

Comment: This answer is misleading. MVCC and `auto_increment_offset` are not considered in this answer, therefore it will lead people to wrong conclusions. I'm downvoting it due to the fact it's completely inaccurate and wrong. Even though it satisfies the OP's "requirement", it will malfunction in a real environment with more than 1 connection accessing the database.

Answer (score 0):

Following query will give you the last id present in table

```
select id from table_name order by id desc limit 1;
```

Updated:

Then you should create table which contains two columns like `table_name`, 
`last_id` and you have to always update the `last_id` when you insert data into particular table. With this way you can fetch the Last id inserted to table.

Comment: Yeah, that would totally work, if you don't remove any records, but if you remove only one from the bottom, then bam, you will get a previous ID.

Comment: May be it's not good idea but then you have to create a table where you insert the table id of that table and update it when you insert into table.